Google Chat App not receiving messages from some users in the workspace
I've just started experimenting with google chat apps using app script.  I followed the instructions on this link:
Build a Google Chat app with Google Apps Script
I followed this link to publish the app:
Publish Google Chat apps
My App script has this code from the original template:
function onMessage(event) 
{
  var name = "";

  if (event.space.type == "DM") {
    name = "You";
  } else {
    name = event.user.displayName;
  }
  var message = name + " said \"" + event.message.text + "\"";

  return { "text": message };
}

When i add this app to my own is, i'm able to send a message and get a response, it also works for a colleague of mine who is an organization admin.  However for other members of the workspace, they are able to find the app and add it. But when they try to send a message on DM, it gives a message " not responding"
Not sure what needs to be done.  Looks like some sort of issue with access policy, but being new to GCP, i am not sure where to find it.
When the user sends a hello message to the app, it should have sent back a You said "hello"

From the example in the link, i had used the test deployment id for the app script for the Gooogle Chat API Configurtion on the cloud project. After i made a new deployment of the app script and replaced the test deployment id with the new deployment id, users were able to access the app functionality
